# How to build a question on test cases may have multiple answers in Botium-box?

Tags: forms, testcase, botium-box

I have created a HTTP(S)/JSON Connector to connect my NLP chatbot.
But I encountered a problem when writing test cases.
Because users say that a question may have multiple different responses.
For example, I say "Hi" to the robot, the robot may say "Hello~guy" or "Hello".
For this reason, the test result would be fail.
[This is a test result picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvZt3.png)

I think maybe we can use intent to judge this problem, or let Botium-box judge by adding "or".

And My Chatbot also can response the form , looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2yvM.png) , that I can click the button.

So, I have two questions to ask.

1. How to determine if the intent is using http(s)/json Connector?
2. How to display the form on the Botium box and determine whether the chat bot button is valid?

I have read the wiki, but I can't do it well, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

In Botium there are several options to meet the requirement of being more flexible when asserting the chatbot response.

First of all, you can switch the *Matching Mode* to something different (see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/60817419/What+are+the+Advanced+Scripting+Settings+in+Botium+Box)) - Botium can switch between several options how the text assertions are done, you can even use regular expressions there. By default this is *wildcardIgnoreCase*, which means you can use the asterisk for doing wildcard matching:

```
#me
Hi

#bot
Hello*
```

This appraoch works if the answers are all more or less the same, with some minor deviations. The recommended way of doing this in Botium is using *utterance lists*: instead of having one convo file, this is split in one convo file and a separate utterances file. Before *hello.convo.txt*:

```
#me
Hi

#bot
Hello*
```

Afterwards *hello.convo.txt*:

```
#me
Hi

#bot
UTT_HELLO
```

And *UTT_HELLO.utterances.txt*:

```
UTT_HELLO
Hello
Hello guy
hi dude
```

Now Botium allows any of those three answers wherever this utterance list is references. You can read more about it in the [Botium in a nutshell](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-2-writing-chatbot-tests-8726204c8da6) series.

**Question 2**

Botium can handle buttons, option lists, carousel cards and more (see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/2293815/Botium+Asserters)), but the connector has to be prepared for this kind of content. It depends on the chatbot technology if this is supported or not - see the [list of official Botium connectors](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360553/Botium+Connectors).

In your case, as you are using the generic HTTP/JSON connector, you can either try the *SIMPLEREST_BUTTONS_JSONPATH* capability, or you can add your own request/response hooks as Javascript code - see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: I have create the excel and upload to botium , but the error says "Duplicate user examples Following user examples are appearing more than once in this list: "你好阿，我最擅長聊天呢。", "你好，很高興見到你。", ... BOT_GREETING"

Comment: There is content in excel. https://i.imgur.com/1JNyhy0.png https://i.imgur.com/lYgOqNQ.png